# How to fetch user profile image from firebase storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm new to android development and I have used firebase inside the project and tried all the ways to show the user profile picture inside the image view but none of the solutions works for me. Uploading profile image to firebase is working fine whenever I click on the save button the profile image and cover image uploaded successfully but it's not showing inside the imageview

```
public class Profile extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE = 101;
    public static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 102;
    public static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 111;
    private Uri uri;
    private Uri coverUri;
    EditText fullName, email, phone;
    Button saveProfileBtn, logoutProfileBtn;
    ImageView userProfileImage, userCoverImage;
    ImageButton cameraBtn, userCoverBtn;
    FirebaseStorage storage;
    StorageReference storageReference;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    FirebaseFirestore fStore;
    FirebaseUser fUser;
    String userID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        ActionBar actionBar;
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#3498DB"));
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);

        actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ffffff'>Profile Settings </font>"));

        fullName = findViewById(R.id.userNameProfile);
        email = findViewById(R.id.emailUserProfile);
        phone = findViewById(R.id.phoneNoProfile);
        saveProfileBtn = findViewById(R.id.saveBtnProfile);
        logoutProfileBtn = findViewById(R.id.logoutBtn);
        userProfileImage = findViewById(R.id.proImgProfile);
        cameraBtn = findViewById(R.id.cameraBtnProfile);
        userCoverImage = findViewById(R.id.coverPhotoPS);
        userCoverBtn = findViewById(R.id.coverImageUpload);

        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        storageReference = storage.getReference();

        cameraBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ImagePicker.with(Profile.this)
                        .crop()                 //Crop image(Optional), Check Customization for more option
                        .compress(512)          //Final image size will be less than 1 MB(Optional)
                        .maxResultSize(512, 512)    //Final image resolution will be less than
                        // 512 x 512(Optional)
                        .start(10);
//                uploadImage();
            }
        });

        userCoverBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ImagePicker.with(Profile.this)
                        .crop()                 //Crop image(Optional), Check Customization for more option
                        .compress(512)          //Final image size will be less than 1 MB(Optional)
                        .maxResultSize(512, 512)    //Final image resolution will be less than
                        // 512 x 512(Optional)
                        .start(20);
            }
        });

        userID = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("users").document(userID);
        documentReference.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                fullName.setText(value.getString("fname"));
                email.setText(value.getString("email"));
                phone.setText(value.getString("phone"));
            }
        });

        saveProfileBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                uploadImage(); //Calling function to upload profile image
                coverUploadImage(); //Calling function to upload cover image
                String fname = fullName.getText().toString();
                String femail = email.getText().toString();
                String fphone = phone.getText().toString();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(fname)) {
                    fullName.setError("Please Enter Your Full Name");
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(femail)) {
                    email.setError("Please Enter Your Email Address");
                    return;
                }

                if (fphone.length() < 10) {
                    phone.setError("Phone Number Shouble Be 10 Digit");
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(fphone)) {
                    phone.setError("Please Enter Your Phone Number");
                    return;
                }

                DocumentReference documentReference =
                        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("users").document(userID);
                Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
                user.put("fname", fname);
                user.put("email", femail);
                user.put("phone", fphone);

                documentReference.update(user).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                        Toast.makeText(Profile.this, "Profile Updated Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(Profile.this, "Failed to Update the Profile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        logoutProfileBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), login.class));
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 10) {
            uri = data.getData();
            userProfileImage.setImageURI(uri);
        }
        if (requestCode == 20)
        {
            coverUri = data.getData();
            userCoverImage.setImageURI(coverUri);
        }
    }

    private void showUploadedImage() {
            Uri uri = fUser.getPhotoUrl();
            Glide.with(this).load(uri).into(userProfileImage);
    }

    // Function to upload profile image
    private void uploadImage() {
        if (uri != null) {
            final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading Profile Image");
            progressDialog.show();

            StorageReference ref = storageReference.child("userProfileImages/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
            ref.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(Profile.this, "Profile Picture Uploaded Successfully",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(Profile.this,
                            "Failed to Uploaded Profile Picture"+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot snapshot) {
                    double progress = (100.0*snapshot.getBytesTransferred()/snapshot
                            .getTotalByteCount());
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded "+(int)progress+"%");
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // Function to upload cover image
    private void coverUploadImage() {
        if (coverUri != null) {
            final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading Cover Picture");
            progressDialog.show();

            StorageReference ref =
                    storageReference.child("userCoverImages/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
            ref.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(Profile.this, "Cover Picture Uploaded Successfully",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(Profile.this,
                            "Failed to Upload Cover Picture"+e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot snapshot) {
                    double progress = (100.0*snapshot.getBytesTransferred()/snapshot
                            .getTotalByteCount());
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded "+(int)progress+"%");
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void saveDocument(View view) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Answer (score 1):

You are saying that the uploading is working successfully, so try another way to get the image URL from storage and put the link in the hashmap with the user's phone, name, and email after uploading the image.
So try this:

```
StorageReference ref = storageReference.child("userProfileImages/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

// Use add on progress like this.

ref.putFile(uri).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot snapshot) {

                }

            }).continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                @Override
                public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()){
                        throw task.getException();
                    }

                    return ref.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    String photoUrl = uri.toString();
// This is the uri that you want to use after to put in the user's hashmap
                    Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(photoUrl).into(userProfileImage);
                }
            });
```

Comment: you are wrong.The uri over here is not the image uri. You need to further call another method `getDownloadUrl` and add success listener to it. There you will find the download url in form of a url. Please edit your answer and make it right.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't understand u but I checked the code It works for me tho

Comment: ok ok. got it. I see that yo are using another method. I don't use this so I Flt it wrong. Testi git out makes it work. Sorry and upvoted